# What does this docker run command do?

Tags: java, maven, docker

I have a docker run command, I  am just wondering what the part `-v "..":".." -w ".." maven mvn clean`... is doing?

```
docker run --rm --name ${DOCKER_IMAGE_NAME}_build -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine mvn clean install package
```

I think it is mapping the local volume on the OS "$(pwd)" to the docker folder inside the docker volume which is /usr/src/mymaven, then it executes the command with "w" inside the /usr/src/mymaven" folder but because of the mapping it executes inside the local $pwd directory right? so it executes the `"maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine mvn clean install package"` part, which starts the mvn build process, but what is `maven:3.6.0-jdk`... I know that it is an image, but how does it know where to pull that image from and how is it possible to directly execute that command for maven thereafter for that image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The -v part of that command binds a volume to the container you're starting. In this case -v "$(pwd)":/usr/src/mymaven
adds your current directory as /usr/src/mymaven to the container.

the -w part of the command sets your working dir within the container to /usr/src/mymaven
and the part after that actually

maven:3.6.0-jdk-8-alpine -> this is the container you're starting

mvn clean install package -> this is the command you're starting inside the container (so in the /usr/src/mymaven working directory)

basically this run command starts up a container, runs maven and does this with your current directory where you started as source to run in.

for more info about the arguments: [docker doc on run arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)